# Как изменить параметр fastcgi в конкретном location?

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь изменить значение параметра `fastcgi_read_timeout` для админского раздела, но не выходит.

Вот как выглядит мой конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    root /srv/www/site/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=15552000';

    location /admin/ {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 2;
        add_header X-debug-message-1 "Admin Location" always;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        add_header X-debug-message-2 "Global Location" always;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        add_header X-debug-message-3 "PHP Location" always;
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    include snippets/expires.conf;
    include snippets/gzip.conf;
    include snippets/protect-system-files.conf;
}
```

Файл `fastcgi_params` стандартный, там про таймаут ничего нет.

В конфиге видно, что я вывожу заголовки для дебага - в браузер отдаётся только `X-debug-message-3`. При этом если в location `/admin/` убрать из `try_files` последний вариант (с `/index.php`), то отдаётся заголовок `X-debug-message-1`, но раздел, разумеется, не работает.

Как добиться нужного результата и изменить `fastcgi_read_timeout` для админского раздела?

Comment: А он таки в index.php в результате попадает?

Comment: @AlexeyTen с тем конфигом, который я приложил, попадает и весь код отрабатывает как нужно, но параметр `fastcgi_read_timeout` из `/admin/` не применяется. А если там в `try_files` убрать index.php, то не попадает, что ожидаемо.

Answer (score 0):

В блоке `/admin/` вы ставите параметру `fastcgi_read_timeout` одно значение, а потом директивой `try_files` просите nginx обратиться к другому `location`, в котором параметру `fastcgi_read_timeout` ставится другое значение.

Попробуйте так:

```
location /admin/ {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 2;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location / {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # здесь уберём эту директиву:
    # fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    # ...остальное как есть
}
```

Comment: Не похоже, что проблема в порядке обработки location - ведь если убрать try_files, то заголовки ставятся. Да и в документации по вашей ссылке есть пример, похожий на мой случай, который опровергает ваши слова. Скорее, дело в том, что try_files работает как некий редирект, который чистит все поставленные до этого заголовки и настройки. У меня используется ЧПУ и в URL вообще нет `.php`, а все запросы обрабатываются одним файлов `index.php` в корне.

Comment: Так получается?

Comment: Нет, так тоже не работает.